# Ubuntu 17.04 Bash Scripting Help

Tags: bash

I need help making a specific bash function.

Here is an example of something that I want to do in a terminal:

- run the command `apt-get update` (run this in the background no output)
- then echo ONLY the `urls` that it updates from (not Hit: 1, Hit: 2, etc...) in a list

So basically I need a bash script to find a specific thing such as "Hit: 1, Hit: 2, etc" and output what comes after that in a list.

PS: This is a theoretical example. I don't have any use for these urls.

Comment: Post the script ... apt-get foo | grep <pattern> . You can also simply cat your sources list

Comment: @bodhi.zazen doesn't this comment qualify as an answer :)?

Comment: I was just using that as an example, I am mainly interested in trying to select certain pieces of text and echo only specific parts from it. That was just an eazy example just so the Terminal can output multiple things. I don't really have any use for those urls.

Comment: Depends on what her wants. Might be better to use sed or awk

Comment: There are several tools to edit / select text. cut , grep, sed, awk, perl to name a few.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `--print-uris` argument of the apt-get command to just output the URIs of the update packages. For example:

`sudo apt-get --print-uris update`

will output the list of tarballs and .xz archives. but the list is very unclean and has the following general format.

```
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar.xz' archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_multiverse_dep11_icons-64x64.tar 0
```

however, the output can be cleaned up by simply using `egrep` with the following simple regular expression that can be used to match URLs direct static links to any file.

`sudo apt-get -y --print-uris update | egrep -o -e egrep -o -e "(ht|f)tp://[^\']+"`

to make this into a function,

```
updateURIonly(){
    sudo apt-get -y --print-uris update | egrep -o -e egrep -o -e "(ht|f)tp://[^\']+" ;
}
```

you could also use this to output the URIs of packages for the `upgrade` and/or `dist-upgrade` arguments as well as any other argument that can be passed to the apt-get command.

to make this work with the `upgrade`  argument:

```
upgradeURIonly(){
    sudo apt-get -y --print-uris upgrade | egrep -o -e egrep -o -e "(ht|f)tp://[^\']+" ;
}
```

you can use the URIs from this output to perform a speedy upgrade by using the inherently faster multi-threaded downloaders like `axel` an/or `aria2c`. I have a script on my github which does precisely this thing. i.e. it uses the method shown above to extract a list of URIs and downloads the `.deb` packages to perform a very fast upgrade. speed increases upto 40X. mind you my script uses `axel` so make sure to have `axel` installed before running the script.

to clone my github repo:

`git clone https://github.com/el-beth/apt-faster.git`

Comment: Thanks @endrias but I feel as though my question was unclear of what I was trying to accomplish. Therefore I am going to make another question with more clear instructions and a better example. Because I just used urls as an example of a list of text on a terminal. I just wanted to find a specific line of text and echo what comes after.

Comment: in that case you should learn about `regex`es. they offer a wonderful way to match text that matches a certain pattern (regular expression) of our choosing. These are just the thing for what you are trying to do, which as far as I understand has to do with screen scraping on terminal.

Comment: I'll look into regex es. It sounds like you understand what I am trying to do now. I have a better example in another question I just posted a few seconds ago if you want to see the real project I was trying to do with it.